# process.MainWindowTitle of Visual Studio 2019 is empty

Tags: c#, .net, process

How to get main window title of Visual Studio 2019?


The following code works for Visual Studio 2017 version but is empty for Visual Studio 2019

```
var vsTitle = Process.GetProcesses()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessName.Equals("devenv", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    ?.MainWindowTitle;

Console.Write(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vsTitle) ? "Not Found!" : vsTitle);

Console.Read();
```

Comment: works fine for me. Using VS2019.

Comment: Interestingly, it worked for me after rebooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By closing and reopening the Visual Studio window fixes the problem.
also sometimes when debugging a program title of windows changed to value of breakpoints